# Firebase user gets logged out after a couple of days

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've added email&password, google, facebook authentication in my application. However, I noticed that after some time passes (1,2 days maybe) `firebase.getAuth()` returns null. 
Please note that I haven't called `firebase.unauth()` anywhere in the code, it seems like the authenticated session expires after some time.
Is there a way to make the session not expire after few days? 
I can think of 2 solutions but both seem bad to me:

- Store custom OAuthToken from Google, Facebook (maybe encrypted), email&password combo(worst case) and call the `firebase.authWithOAuthToken()` again and again when the session has become unauthorized
- Bring the user back to login screen asking to perform the authorization again each time the session expires. I think this is even worse than the above because it breaks the UX and potentially upsets the majority of users.

Is there a built-in mechanism to achive the above? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution number 3 and also the cause of this issue. In your firebase dashboard on the Login & Auth tab you can set the session length, default is 24 or 48 hours i think.

So if it's set at 24 hours all sessions will expire after 24 hours like you are seeing right now. But you can change this to 6 months for example.

[image]

Comment: I've updated the setting. It was set to 24h indeed. I'll let you know after a couple of days. Hope it's this simple

Comment: Tried it out after 4 days, and it works. Thanks a lot!